# Laravel , using condition of select box to dictate form validation

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have a newly added select box in my laravel update form:

```
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('statusCode', 'Active') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::select('statusCode', array('A' => 'Yes', 'D' => 'No')) !!}</td>
</tr>
```

Setting it to Yes or No works, and when I submit the form it updates the database record properly but there's a bit of headache with validation.

Technically, if I set it to 'No' to deactivate an image then all I need is the id of the image so I know which one to deactivate but right now it forces validation on unnecessary inputs if they're blank.

So on this block, if my select is set to 'D' or 'No' then I only need to require the id:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'id' => 'required|numeric|unique:jfi.image_files,id,' . $id,
        'prdGrpNum' => 'numeric|required',
        'altGrpDesc' => 'required',
        'cover1' => 'numeric|required', 
        'color1' => 'numeric|required', 
        'typeId' => 'numeric|required'
    ]);
```

However, this next block I'm checking any filled out inputs against the database to keep data sanitized.

So for this block, I want to say "IF select box is set to 'D'/'No' AND this field is empty, don't validate. Else, do this existing validation for the imageService"

```
 if(!$imageService->validImageTypeId($request->typeId))
        return back()->withErrors("Invalid image type given");
```

How can I use the value of the select box to allow empty fields to skip validation but filled out fields to still be validated?

Comment: hi! I suggest you read this part of laravel validation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `required_if` rule:
`required_if:anotherfield,value,...`

```
'prdGrpNum' => 'required_if:statusCode,Yes|numeric'
```

and the same for the other rules.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will do it for that main block! So for the second code block, can I just use statusCode and 'Yes' as the conditional in my if statement? ANd then check for it being null if so?

Comment: That's a custom validation there so you can do it however you want. Or you can create a custom validation rule per the documentation link shared in a comment in your main question.